# Fill multiple Nan values with random numbers and not just one single number

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe with multiple `NaN` values. I want to fill each with a random number `between 0,1`.  I tried `fillna` but that fills the code with just one value.

We can use `itterows` but it consumes a lot of resources. Is there any way else we can do it and if yes then how? The following is an example of my dataframe.

```
> df 
   a   b   c   d
0  1  10   na  na
1  2  20   40  30
2  24 na   na  na
```

expected output

```
> df 
   a     b     c     d
0  1    10     0.7   0.9
1  2    20     40    30
2  24   0.9    0.34  0.532
```

basically replacing `na` anything between `(0,1)`

Comment: Please show what you have tried, or at least provide a small sample of what your data looks like.

Comment: @pjs I have modefied my question, let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Provided expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own formula along with random number:

In below solution, I am multiplying column `a` with random number and taking only fractions as you want number between 0 to 1.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,24], 'b':[10,20, np.nan],'c':[np.nan,40,np.nan],'d':[np.nan,30,np.nan]})

for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = np.where(df[c].isnull(),(df['a']*random.random())%1,df[c])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     a          b          c          d                                                                                                
0   1.0  10.000000   0.526793   0.678061                                                                                                
1   2.0  20.000000  40.000000  30.000000                                                                                                
2  24.0   0.865441   0.643032   0.273461
```